# R function for finding the sensitivity given an alpha value

Tags: r, statistics, model-fitting

I am new to data analysis with R so any help is appreciated.
I have a dataset with some explanatory variables and one target variable. The target variable is either Yes or No only. So I would like to use logistic regression for model fitting.

This is how I plot a roc curve

```
myModel = train(
  myTarget ~ .,
  myTrainData,
  method = "glm",
  metric = "ROC",
  trControl = myControl,
  na.action  = na.pass
  )
myPred = predict(myModel , newdata = myTestData, type="prob")
eval <- evalm(data.frame(myPred , myTestData$myTarget)
eval$roc
```

Now, I would like to find the sensitivity given an alpha value / Type I error

And show the information like the following if possible, how can I achieve it?

```
confusionMatrix(myPred,  reference = myTestData$myTarget)
```

Comment: Instead of `type="prob"` use `type="response"` in predict function

Comment: Error: type must be either "raw" or "prob"

Comment: I don't think there is a type called response

Comment: Check the values of `myPred` it will be between 0 and 1. You can convert them to 0 or 1 based on threshold and then run `confusionMatrix(myPred,  reference = myTestData$myTarget)'.

Comment: do you have an example for it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: say I would like to look for the sensitivity when alpha = 5%. How do I extract from myPred